# How to find pointer event type like pointer entered or pointer existed in UWP or C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

How can we find which pointer event type from `RoutedEventArgs`?
Like I have one `HyperlinkButton` and normal `Button`.
I want to use same method when mouse `PointerEntered`/`PointerExited` on both elements.

```
HyperlinkButton hLinkBtn1 = new HyperlinkButton();
Button btn1 = new Button();
hLinkBtn1.PointerEntered += myEvent;
hLinkBtn1.PointerExited += myEvent;
btn1.PointerEntered += myEvent;
btn1.PointerExited += myEvent;

private void myEvent(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO
    // get pointer entered OR exited
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `sender` argument using the [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) operator:

```
private void myEvent(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
        //button was clicked...
    }
    else
    {
        HyperlinkButton hpl = sender as HyperlinkButton;
        if (hpl != null)
        {
            //hyperlink was clicked...
        }
    }
}
```

> My question is not about Element, I want to know which Event triggered. When mouse over / out, get pointerEntered / pointerExited

You could use anonymous event handlers that calls a method that accepts an argument that can be used to tell whether a `PointerEntered` or `PointerExited` event was raised:

```
btn1.PointerEntered  += (ss, ee) => myEventHandler(ee, "PointerEntered");
btn1.PointerExited  += (ss, ee) => myEventHandler(ee, "PointerExited");
...

private void myEventHandler(PointerRoutedEventArgs ee, string eventType)
{
    switch(eventType)
    {
        case "PointerEntered":
            //...
        break;
        case "PointerExited":
       //...
        break;
}
```

Comment: My question is not about Element, I want to know which Event triggered. When mouse over / out, get pointerEntered  / pointerExited

Comment: Use different event handlers then. It makes no sense to use the same event handler if you want to be able to distinguish between different types of events...

Comment: Then tell me which is the different event handler. yes some time it make sense to use common method.

Comment: Use anonymous event handlers then. See my edited answer.

Comment: Do you have any idea about anonymous event handlers in C++/CX. I am new to .Net. (C#, C++)

Comment: Are you using C++ or C#? Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: C++/CX, UWP, Issue is same, but language is different